# C# Parallel.ForEach, not working as expected

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

In my console app facing a strange issue with Parallel Foreach loop, I looping through one entitycollection i.e. Poll and calling one api to get url, and one function getTemplateDiscription to get the various language contents. The issue is when I am running it with single thread it works properly but when I am running with multiple thread, content is not getting set for all records i.e. some content is getting set as null. But working fine with single thread. Following is the code snippet:

```
//Global variable - Outside the Parallel Foreach. 
  //Guid contactId, templateIdEnglish, templateIdEnglishReminder, templateIdGerman, templateIdGermanReminder  
    Parallel.ForEach<acn_poll, OrganizationServiceProxy>(
        pollList,
        new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism },
        () => { return CreateServiceProxy(); },
        (poll, loopstate, index, threadProxy) =>
        {
            //Logic to call api
            var content1 = getTemplateDescription(contactId, templateIdEnglish, threadProxy);
            var content2 = getTemplateDescription(contactId, templateIdEnglishReminder, threadProxy);
            var content3 = getTemplateDescription(contactId, templateIdGerman, threadProxy);
            var content3 = getTemplateDescription(contactId, templateIdGermanReminder, threadProxy);
            //update poll entity with Content
        }
```

I have tried to debug in multithreading mode (i.e. maxDegreeOfParallelism > 1)  but didn't get any clue as code is running is zigzag form due to multithreading. Following is the function which is not returning the output as expected. In single thread setting all content field properly but in multithreading mode somehow its returning null.

```
public static string getTemplateDescription(Guid contactId, Guid templateId, IOrganizationService service)
{        

        if (templateId == Guid.Empty)
            return "";

        string content = string.Empty;

    InstantiateTemplateRequest instTemplateReq = new InstantiateTemplateRequest
    {
        TemplateId = templateId,
        ObjectId = contactId,
        ObjectType = "Contact"
    };

    InstantiateTemplateResponse instTemplateResp = (InstantiateTemplateResponse)service.Execute(instTemplateReq);

    if (instTemplateResp != null)
    {
        Entity template = instTemplateResp.EntityCollection.Entities[0];
        if (template != null && template.Attributes.Contains("description"))
        {                       
            content = template.Attributes["description"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your post and post your code as `code`

Comment: show us what you have  tried

Comment: I don't see any declaration of `content` in `getTemplateDescription`. If that's not a local variable, then I strongly suspect that's part of the problem. (And what do you want it to return if `instTemplateResp` *is* null?)

Comment: Hi Jon, I have updated the code snippet, I believe everything happens with some reason I missing that point and due to multithreading unable to debug it. any suggestion?

Comment: where does `entityName` come from?

Comment: My guess would be that IOrganizationService is not thread safe, i.e it has some shared mutable state not protected by locks.

Comment: Do we need the IOrganizationService to be thread-safe ? as you can see in code snipped I am creating one instance per thread. If yes then please provide some more detail to get it done. I am following this blog - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2012/09/07/optimize-crm-2011-service-channel-allocation-for-multi-threaded-processes-using-net-task-parallel-library-tpl-and-a-thread-local-service-proxy/

Comment: Observed one more thing - I was printing count within the parallel-foreach, but it was inconsistent - Interlocked.Add(ref count, 1); I mean sometimes the same number was repeating 2-3 times, but when I put print just after the increment it started showing correctly. If I put my logic between the Interlocked.Add(ref count, 1); and log print it again started showing inconsistent iteration.